# how to fix Bootstrap 3 error in Angular project

Tags: angular

I am adding bootstrap 3 in my angular project using CLI and then when I opened bootstrap.min.css file I see error as the value of background-color is not correct.

background-color:#000\9;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);border:1px solid #fff;border-radius:10px}

is there anyone who is also facing this error and if yes then what should be exact value of this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let's remove: `#000\9` and change to `#0009` and run again. Because `#000\9` not exists
[image]